# Laravel - How to send email to all users

Tags: email, laravel, laravel-4

Im struggling to make a code that sends email to my subscribed users. I want to pass body to view according to users default language, can anyone help me ?

My code:

```
if($newsletter->save())
            {
                //get users to send to
                $users = User::where('newsletter', '=', '1')->Where('activated', '=', '1')->get();

                //Send to all users subscribed
                foreach($users as $user)
                {
                    //set info according to user default lang
                    if($user->default_lang == 'pt')
                    {
                        $body = $newsletter_pt;
                        $subject = Input::get('subject_PT');
                    }
                    elseif($user->default_lang == 'de')
                    {
                        $body = $newsletter_de;
                        Input::get('subject_DE');
                    }

                    $data = array(
                        'body' => $body,
                        'subject' => $subject
                    );

                    $from_name = Input::get('from_name');
                    $from_email = Input::get('from_email');

                    //QUEUE The Newsletters to send
                    Mail::queue('admin.newsletters.template1', $data, function($message) use ($user, $subject, $from_name, $from_email)
                    {
                        $message->from($from_email, $from_name);
                        $message->bcc($user->email, $user->name);
                        $message->subject($subject);
                    });

                } //end foreach

                return Redirect::To('admin/newsletters')->with('message', array("1" => "Newsletter enviada com sucesso !"));
            }
```

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: What is the problem that you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that the `$data` array has the information you expect to pass into the view before you call `Mail::queue()`. It should pass both a `$body` and `$subject` variable to your view.

You might also try using `Mail::send()` instead of `Mail::queue()` and see if it makes a difference (if you're not using a queueing system). Sometimes the `queue()` method can trip up when serializing Eloquent models, so if `$newsletter_pt` or `$newsletter_de` are Eloquent models they might not make it to the view intact.